# How to create globally available libraries in Java?

Tags: java, installation, global, package

What I mean is, in Java there is a standard set of packages that can be referenced from any program in any context on the computer. So when I want to process raster images I just add `import java.awt.image.BufferedImage` to the top of my file and I able to use that pre-built class without referencing the actual java.awt.image package files at all during compilation and run time. **Where are these globally importable packages kept and/or how can I make my package files globally available in the same way?**

I have been writing a lot of small helper programs lately, most of which do very similar things, and it would be convenient for me to be able to reuse code without explicitly referencing my package files.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why dont you create a lib-project in eclipse and reference it to all your new  projects ???

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa Because 1) I don't use eclipse I usually just make the .java file in a text editor and then compile with the terminal. 2) I was curious how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you CAN place any jar library you want into your JRE to achieve same result - classes from this jar will be available in classpath at runtime though it is not recommended to do so without a reason :) But if you are just learning and do not want bother with build tools it's OK

```
[java-home]/lib/ext - standart place for your libraries
[java-home]/lib/endorsed - place for the libraries which API's overwrite default JRE's ones
```

Comment: Could you add a little more information about how to add a jar to my JDK? Sorry if that's an annoying question but I am not *really* a Java programmer and I don't know where/what my JDK actually is. Is that the directory referenced by `JAVA_HOME`? Do I just put my jar in that directory?

Comment: ok, added some info. Yes, [java-home] in my example has a value of your JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: Ok so are you saying that `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext` is for standard libraries and `$JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed` is for my own libraries? Kind of like `/usr/lib` vs. `/usr/local/lib`? Also why is this not recommended without a strong reason?

Comment: no, with very high probability you can place your libraries in $JAVA_HOME/lib/ext. But if they clash somehow with standart JDK libs and classes put your jars into $JAVA_HOME/lib/endorsed dir (99% you won't need it). Placing your jars in JDK is not recommended because it is not a good idea to make your program platform and machine dependent (or even change JDK behaviour). It should be as self-sufficient as possible - allowing people to checkout app from github and run it on standart JDK (for example). Build tools deal with this issue

Comment: Ahh I see. Let me try this and if it works I will approve your answer.

Comment: More info about your case (including Linux part) you can find here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html